# Method Definition Not In @implementation Context: Error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

When I try to import it gives error at the import stating "method definition not in @implementation context". I think the error lies within the following code...

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [self.jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
static NSString *Prospects = @"agencyname";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Prospects];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:Prospects] autorelease];
}

// setting the text
cell.text = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"agencyname"];    
// Set up the cell
return cell;
 }


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
ViewAgencyController *dvController = [[ViewAgencyController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewAgency" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
[dvController release];
dvController = nil; 

}
```

Cant Figure it out.

Comment: Did you accidentally put these method definitions in some class' header, within its interface? What file are these in?

Comment: The didSelectRowAtIndexPath is the only thing I modified that threw this error. I did #import ViewAgencyController and added that bottom section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All objective-C method definitions must be between `@implemention` and `@end` compiler directives.  Without those, there's no way for the compiler to know what class you want the method to belong to.

Look at your header and make sure you have an `@end` directive to close your class declaration, and look at your .m file and make sure you have an `@implementation` directive before, and an `@end` after your method implementations.

Comment: Your right, I had some extra crap in my header file after @end... thanks.